# Debug embedded browser view in native Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, debugging, webview, safari

My web application is malfunctioning when running inside the native Facebook app for iOS (clicking in a link does not open Safari, but an embedded browser inside the app).

When running the iOS emulator, in my desktop safari I have the option to attach the debugger to mobile Safari... So I was wondering if it was possible to do the same with an embedded view running in an iPhone connected with the USB cable.

Another problem that I've seen is that the Facebook app makes a very aggressive caching of any web content, so I cannot refresh the page and see if my changes work. The only way I have found to clean the web cache of the native iOS Facebook app is uninstalling and installing it again. A solution for that will be very welcome too.

Comment: This is quite annoying, as I'm trying to debug a page that behaves differently under FB's embedded browser vs. Mobile Safari.app.  Going to try some alternative debugging techniques, but yeah, not being able to attach to an embedded browser on iOS devices is frustrating.

Comment: Same here. Driving me insane.

Comment: Yep, same here. FB embedded browser doesn't seem to post hidden form values, but nothing is sure without debugging tools.

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this yet? I can't debug why my FB.ui share isn't working...

Comment: If somebody found a solution, it wasn't shared here... :/

Comment: I am unable to save photos even the browser location is http://path/to/theimage.jpg.  I get a magnifying glass. I used -webkit-user-select: none on the img, and works in safari browser.

Comment: at today i have similar problems , if someone knows something it would be useful to share here..

Comment: Same here. My issue is with the browser in the iOS Twitter app. How are we supposed to debug this!? Does the answer below work? Don't see it accepted or commented on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug on Facebook Internal Browser (Mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199489/how-to-debug-on-facebook-internal-browser-mobile)

Answer (score 6):

I think the solution to this problem is to use http://jsconsole.com with [remote debugging](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html). It will stream in exceptions and log statements remotely.

Comment: That doesn't work anymore: https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/issues/101

Answer (score 1):

I am using this. It works fine to me https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs
very easy to install

```
$ npm i -g vorlon
$ vorlon
```

after installation, you need to add this to your app

```
 <script src="http://localhost:1337/vorlon.js"></script>
```

Comment: An old tool but still work like a charm, thanks for the answer

Comment: VorlonJS hasn't been updated for 5 years, can I debug CSS for a website in Facebook Messenger's new integrated browser with this? Messenger doesn't seem to use Android Webview anymore. So how can anyone debug in the same way as with Chrome Developer Tools??