# Facebook app browser debugging

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, debugging

**Background:**
I'm building a responsive website (html5,css3,js), but noticed some functionality doesn't work when being viewed inside of Facebooks in-app browser. The site works fine in chrome/firefox/safari.  However, when a user is using the facebook mobile app, and clicks a link to my site, it launches the in-app browser window. The site loads, but some functionality doesn't work.

**Questions:**
A)  Are there any tools that I can use to debug my site in the facebook in-app browser? (ie: firebug)
I have searched high and low, but haven't found an easy solution.

or B)  Is there any way that my site can detect that browser and launch a different one...or something along those lines?

Thanks for any help on this one!

Comment: There is no tool to debug inside the in-app browser, you'll need to use your own logs. You can detect the user agent of the browser and do something different if you need: http://www.surinderbhomra.com/Blog/Post/2015/01/03/Detecting-Facebook-In-App-Browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199489/how-to-debug-on-facebook-internal-browser-mobile